# SQL order by and list

Tags: sql, list, sql-order-by

I am fairly new to SQL and i have tried my hardest to code this, but it does not seem to work for me so help would be appreciated very much.

The question states that i need to list the total number of books published by each publisher and then list them from highest and lowest using the publisher code.

I have gotten this far;

```
SELECT COUNT (pub_code)
FROM Library_Books
GROUP BY pub_code
ORDER BY pub_code
```

Any help would be appreciated whatsoever

Comment: So what is the problem?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT kb_pub_code
,COUNT (*) as 'TotalBooks'
FROM Library_Books
GROUP BY kb_pub_code
ORDER BY TotalBooks desc
```

Edit: with the additional information of possible duplicates you may wish to use a CTE.

```
With DistinctList as(
Select Distinct kb_pub_code as 'PubCode'
,kb_title as 'Title' 
FROM Library_Books)

Select PubCode
,Count(*) as 'TotalBooks'
From DistinctList
Group by PubCode
ORDER BY TotalBooks desc
```

Comment: Thank you, really helped

Comment: @KyleBenjamin please accept this as answered if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT kb_pub_code, COUNT (kb_pub_code)    
FROM Library_Books    
GROUP BY kb_pub_code    
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Instead of `Order by 2` is better be explicit and use `ORDER BY COUNT (kb_pub_code)`

Comment: Thank you, really helped

Comment: Even better to order by a column alias! (Take a look at @Aaron Dietz' answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close:

```
SELECT kb_pub_code, COUNT(*) TotalBooks
FROM Library_Books
GROUP BY kb_pub_code
ORDER BY TotalBooks DESC
```

`TotalBooks` is an alias for the count column, which is counting the total number of rows for each `kb_pub_code`

You can reference a column alias in your `ORDER BY`: ie.`ORDER BY TotalBooks DESC`

Note, if books can be repeated in the `Library_Books` table, you may want a `DISTINCT` count.  Something like:

```
SELECT kb_pub_code, COUNT(DISTINCT title) TotalBooks
FROM Library_Books
GROUP BY kb_pub_code
ORDER BY TotalBooks DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, really helped

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` `DESC` will sort in descending order.  The publisher code should be included in the result set (`SELECT`) otherwise you would not know which publisher is the count for.

```
SELECT kb_pub_code, COUNT (kb_pub_code)    
FROM Library_Books    
GROUP BY kb_pub_code    
ORDER BY COUNT(kb_pub_code) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, really helped